# pygsheets freeze first row

Tags: python, google-sheets, pygsheets

So I am playing with google spreadsheets and there is a handy feature to freeze first row or/and first column. But is there a way to do this through [pygsheets](https://github.com/nithinmurali/pygsheets)?
Or maybe other python library?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the `frozen_row` and `frozen_column` worksheet properties. To freeze the first 2 rows, use `wks.frozen_rows=2`. See more info in [docs](http://pygsheets.readthedocs.io/en/latest/worksheet.html)

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:

```
import pygsheets
client = pygsheets.authorize(service_account_file='your json file address')
sh = client.open('your spreadsheet title')

#if you have multiple worksheets
worksheet_names = ['wks1 title','wks2 title',...]
for name in worksheet_names:
    ws = sh.worksheet_by_title(name)
    ws.frozen_rows = 1
```